# Use of datepicker and jQuery dialog features contemporarily

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui-datepicker

I need to use datepicker and jQuery dialog features using Bootstrap.  To do this, I used these links:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/bootstrap.3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="resources/bootstrap.3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<link href="resources/css/font-awesome-4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="resources/jquery_ui/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<link href="resources/css/tables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="resources/css/buttons.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="resources/css/forms.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="resources/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>


<!-- for the date -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/css/datepicker.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/css/datepicker3.min.css" />

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
```

in the body of jsp:

```
$(function(){

    dialog_info =  $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
          autoOpen: false,
          resizable: false,
          height: "auto",
          width: 300,
          modal: true

        }); 

    });

<div id="dialog" title="Caricamento pagina">
  <p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float:left; margin:12px 12px 20px 0;"></span><span id="warn_message"></span></p>
</div>
```

I can't reach the result to make "Caricamento pagina" a dialog, making so it hidden in the beginning and then showing it, because the code in `$(function)` doesn't work.  I tried also with:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    dialog_info =  $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
          autoOpen: false,
          resizable: false,
          height: "auto",
          width: 300,
          modal: true

        }); 

    }
)
```

(should be the same), without results.  Maybe there are compatibility problems in the links above? Consider that, in another page, where datepicker is not needed, the code works with these links:

```
<link rel='stylesheet'  href='webjars/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css'>       
<script type="text/javascript" src="webjars/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="webjars/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="resources/css/tables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="resources/css/buttons.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="resources/css/forms.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="resources/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="resources/css/font-awesome-4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="resources/jquery_ui/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

But in the first page I need datepicker so link showed above are necessary. Please, help.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're calling jQuery twice in your first code block

Comment: Fixed formatting and spelling issues

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem getting all linked files, putting them in local folder and linking the jsp to them locally.  Suppose they weren't loaded anytime needed...